# Debugging jQuery and zclip plugin

Tags: jquery, debugging, jquery-plugins, flash, zclip

Can anyone tell me why this code is not working?

Link to zclip: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/f4gZA/

Thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/jquery.snippet.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#copy-button").zclip({
    path: "http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
    copy: function() {
        return $(this).prev().text();
    }
});

});
</script>

<div id='copy'>Test</div>
<button id='copy-button'>copy</button>
```

Comment: This jsFiddle of your code works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pntm9/ so it doesn't look like there's anything wrong with the code you've presented here.  More likely something different/wrong in your actual implementation or a problem with Flash on your local browser/system.

Comment: jsFiddle works. this is the same code i added here. when i put this in a HTML file it dosent work. thats the problem

Comment: Obviously there's something different about the web page environment that causes the problem.  There's not much we can do here unless you give us some more clues about what is different or post a link to the actual web page that has the problem.

Comment: I got it to work. problem comes when im using local host. when i uploaded to the sever it work. thanks

Comment: Flash won't allow the copy operation when on local host unless you ease some permission in Flash.

Answer (score 1):

> I got it to work. problem comes when im using local host. when i uploaded to the sever it work. thanks